# How to do this function call in jquery?

Tags: jquery, button, click

I have a submit button click which is common for so many popups. Here's my html and click event,

```
<div class="myContainer ">
        <button onclick="javascript:;" class="shcBtn shcBtnCTA submit">
            <span>Close</span>
        </button>
</div>

$('.myContainer .submit').on('click', function(){
        var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
            onReady: function(){
            // you need to wait for the onReady callback before using the socket
                socket.postMessage("submitflow");
            }
        });
    });
```

Now in one particular flow i have to make my submit button call an ajax call and if it is successful then i should proceed with the socket call. I dont want to alter my click function since its used every where. Is there any other way of doing it???

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the click event manually, which will trigger the handler

```
$('.myContainer .submit').click()
```

or

```
$('.myContainer .submit').trigger('click')
```

Comment: i want the ajax call to happen before the socket call.. How can i do that?? And that too only on ajax call success..

Comment: on the success callback of the ajax call, you can do this

Answer (score 0):

If something is particular, you should make it particular in the markup, so it doesn't get the same handler as all the other:

```
<div class="myContainer">
    <!-- normal container -->
</div>

<div class="particularContainer">
    <!-- particularContainer -->
</div>
```

Then, you could distinguish the particular case like this:

```
$('.myContainer .submit').on('click',function(){
    beforeSubmit();
});

$('.particularContainer .submit').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({/* ... */}).done(function(){
        beforeSubmit();
    });
});
```